# "No instance for (Ord k)" when implementing Functor over Data.Map.Map

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor, tail-recursion

I am attempting to implement the Functor fmap over a Data.Map.Map, but I am getting an error.  I'm sure I don't need to convert the Map to and from a List in order to get this working, but this is the best I've come up with so far.

```hs
class Functor' f where
    fmap' :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance Functor' (Map.Map k) where
    fmap' f m
        | Map.null m = Map.empty
        | otherwise = let x:xs = Map.toList m
                          mtail = Map.fromList xs
                          a = fst x
                          b = snd x
                      in  Map.insert a (f b) (fmap f mtail)
```

The error:

```
No instance for (Ord k)
  arising from a use of `Map.fromList'
In the expression: Map.fromList xs
In an equation for `mtail': mtail = Map.fromList xs
In the expression:
  let
    x : xs = Map.toList m
    mtail = Map.fromList xs
    a = fst x
    ....
  in Map.insert a (f b) (fmap f mtail)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just put `Ord` into context: `instance Ord k => Functor' (Map.Map k) where`.

Comment: Nice, thank you!  Is there a better way than converting to and from a List?

Comment: Yes, there is a better way to write `fmap` for `Functor (Map k)` without using lists and `Ord k` constraint at all. This is how `Data.Map.map` (== `fmap` for `Map k`) works: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers-0.4.2.1/src/Data-Map.html#map. But if you want to use `toList` / `fromList` then something like `fmap' f = Map.fromList . map (second f) . Map.toList` would be simpler (`second` is from `Control.Arrow`).

Comment: Note that the [set-monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad) package provides `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` instances (along with various others) for a data type that represents a `Set`. Internally it uses `Data.Set`, but performs additional bookkeeping in order to obey functor & monad laws. [edit: doh this question is about Map. I suppose the same could be done for Map as well?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to not assigning the Ord predicate to the type-variable k. Just do this:

```
instance Ord k => Functor' (Map.Map k) where
```